# How does Google Photos app's "auto" filter works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, image-editing, camanjs

I am making an image enhancement app using CamanJS. And I want to know-how does the auto image filter works in google photos. Is there a way I can replicate it or is there any google API that is available. I have tried searching but not found any option.

Comment: did you figure out any solution?